# Не удается преобразовать тип "System.Web.Mvc.SelectList" в "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Решил сделать фильтрацию через *DropDownList* но функция ругается!!!

Представление с функцией (рис 1.1):

[image: Представление с функцией]

Файл *HomeViewModel.cs* с основными моделями (рис 1.2):

[image: Модель]

Comment: Зачем вы напихали нерелевантные метки? Оставьте только те технологии, которые реально используются, остальные удалите. / В процессе обдумывания меток как раз осознаете, что это **разные** технологии и не стоит даже пытаться тянуть код из одной в другую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

РЕШЕНО: Похоже на то что SelectList из System.Web.Mvc устарел, подключайте Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering и используйте эту реализацию SelectList!!!

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
```

вместо

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```